# Получить элемент, по которому произошел клик (jquery)?

Tags: jquery

На странице имеется множество различных элементов. Выделить элемент (id например) нельзя. Как получить элемент, по которому произошел клик?

Comment: У этого множества элементов есть что-то общее? Например один класс, или какой-то атрибут?

Comment: @Anamnian Нет. Требуется вначале получить элемент, а уже потом его разобрать по запчастям =)

Comment: все зависит от того, как именно и куда навешивается обработчик. Это может быть как `this`, так и `e.target`

Comment: В функции-обработчике клика см. указатель this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В переменной `el` будет ваш элемент:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var el = $(e.target);
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target)
}); - получается, практически в точности, как в ванильном js?

Comment: Да, согласно https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700710/6677992

Comment: Продано! Благодарю! =)